# determine the Windows Server Make model and Serial Number using SNMP

Tags: c#, snmp

How can i determine the Windows Server Make model and Serial Number using SNMP. Need to know the hardware details of the windows server . Please provide me SNMP OID for SunOS systems

Comment: Yeah am able to identify the Windows or UNIX system based on SysDesc oid but i want to get more details . is it feasible to know the manufacturer , model and serial number of remote machine based on SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Windows SNMP MIB documents after enabling SNMP services. The files reside inside %windir%. From there you can see the set of objects Microsoft implemented. But it might not provide everything you need, as Microsoft recommends WMI.